# EXCEL 2nd Enable Editing Button appears after already Enabling

Tags: vba, excel

I have an excel workbook that I download using simple HTML portal that I coded. When I download the workbook it automatically renames it as "myWorkbook (27)" or whatever number of times it has been put in the downloads folder.

I have some code that changes the Save As location of the workbook to the original location that it was downloaded from. See:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
'Check to see if another workbook with the same name is open -- close if so.
If IsOpenWorkbook("myWorkbook.xlsm", True) Then
    Workbooks("myWorkbook.xlsm").Close saveChanges = False
End If
ThisWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:="\\999.9.9.99\folder\anotherFolder\myWorkbook.xlsm"
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub
```

This has worked fine for almost a month but recently has been performing erratically. When I first download the sheet, it has the regular "Enable Editing" prompt which I accept. After accepting, the name  of the workbook changes suggesting the code as run, but then has another "Enable Editing" prompt which, if I accept, will crash Excel.

Any insights appreciated.